# TCO-Timestamp in Microsoft User-Agents

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, user-agent

In MSIE versions before 9.0, part of the user-agent string are so called "feature tokens" which are [read from the windows registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In user-agent strings of Windows Tablet PCs and/or Media Center PCs is a "Feature" which apparently is a sort of time-stamp.

It starts with "TCO_" (for example `"TCO_20131121180135"`) it is NOT the time of the request and dates usually a few hours BEFORE the request. For example search for "TCO_" on [this user-agent list](http://www.vwp-online.de/ua.php?ua_type=mobile-browser).

Here comes my question: Does anybody know what the exact purpose of this field is? What software writes it to the Windows registry?

Topics associated with TCO I could identify are:

- "Total Cost of Ownership",
- an file extension of a "T9000 Object Module" (found nothing relevant on this topic)
- and the [TCO-Certification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCO_Certification) – this has something to do with power consumption, but what would be the purpose of a related TCO-timestamp?

Another aspect may be the so-called Watchdog Timer (WDT) on some Intel chipsets – but again, I could find no relation to Media Center PCs.

Could anybody shed light on this TCO-timestamp in Microsoft user-agents?